# Better way of using "self." in background thread?

Tags: swift, self, dispatch-queue

After adding `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {}` to a single function of my code (Xcode 10, Swift 5), the scrollbar looks like this:

[image]

These are more than 40 calls to vars and other funcs that need a "self.".

Fixing this isn't hard (Editor > Fix All Issues) but it reduces readability a lot.

I'm aware that it's possible to create new copies of/references to these vars and using them instead of the ones outside but then there'll be a lot of new copies/references.

Is there a third way of fixing this that helps with readability but doesn't change the initial code (too much)?

Comment: Please post some code what you have tried.

Comment: You should _always_ say `self`. That looks better, not worse. The mistake was omitting it in the first place.  Put in `self` here and everywhere.

Comment: @SagarChauhan Sorry, not sure how code would help here. Everyone knows what `self.` looks like and I'm not directly trying to solve a problem with my code but more looking for an alternative.

Comment: @matt `You should always say self` - Even if you aren't in a background thread? I've never seen anyone do that and imo there's really no need for `self` (unless you are using a second thread) because it doesn't add anything and reduces readability too.

Comment: I disagree. I think omitting `self` reduces readability and does add something (readability). Otherwise you've just got all these unidentifiable terms floating around. Every message should have a recipient. Of course that's a matter of opinion / style, but my point is, so is your question.

Comment: Could you please post an example of when I should definitely use it in your opinion then, even though the code is running on the main thread. The function I'm currently working on has more than 40 `self` because of the second thread. I know these vars are declared "outside" and it's easy to see that they are and yet there's this pink `self` "blob" (I'm aware you can change the colors in Xcode) in front of almost every one that distracts from the actual name of the var.

Comment: Also, while using `self.` when Xcode doesn't cry for it, is opinion-based, it's not when there's code in a second thread and this is exactly what I was/am looking an alternative for. So in the end there's nothing opinion-based about the question.

Comment: Extract that code in the closure into a method/nested function and pass the name of the method/nested function instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a nested function or another method to put the code you want to execute in, then pass that nested function or method into `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Here's an example with a nested function:

Original code:

```
class Foo {
    var a = 0
    var b = 0
    var c = 0

    func f() {
        a = 1
        b = 1
        c = 1
    }
}
```

Doing it asynchronously:

```
class Foo {
    var a = 0
    var b = 0
    var c = 0

    func f() {
        func doAsync() {
            a = 1
            b = 1
            c = 1
        }
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async(execute: doAsync)
    }
}
```

As you can see, you don't need to add any `self`s.

Comment: That's the kind of solution I was looking for - clean and easy. Thanks, I'm going to try it with my code!

Comment: Sorry, I won't be able to test it until tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Just tested it and it's working, thanks!